# Excel VBA deleting rows based on certain encounters

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet which contains numerical values and texts in between.
What I want is to remove the complete rows where-ever it starts with "Station"
till it encounters "Precipitable".
I am new to this and tried with available codes online but couldn't succeed.

For example the data looks like:

```
PRES    HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
hPa      m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1002.0    14   28.4   25.3    83   20.78     45      2  301.4  363.0  305.1
1000.0    34   28.2   25.2    84   20.69     45      2  301.4  362.7  305.1
969.9    304   25.6   23.6    89   19.36    330      7  301.4  358.7  304.9
940.0    581   23.0   22.0    94   18.07    330      9  301.4  354.9  304.7
937.0    609   22.8   21.8    94   17.84    330      9  301.5  354.3  304.7
920.0    769   21.8   20.3    91   16.59    335     10  302.1  351.2  305.1
904.8    914   21.8   18.9    84   15.47    340     11  303.5  349.6  306.3
850.0   1458   21.8   13.8    60   11.80     25     11  309.0  345.1  311.2
795.0   2039   21.8    8.8    43    9.02     34      8  314.9  343.4  316.6
786.3   2133   21.1    8.1    43    8.66     35      7  315.1  342.6  316.8
700.0   3125   13.2    0.2    41    5.58     79      9  317.1  335.2  318.1
685.0   3307   11.6   -1.4    40    5.07     87      9  317.3  333.8  318.2
623.0   4090    2.6   -1.2    76    5.66    122     10  315.7  333.9  316.8
600.0   4394    0.8   -3.9    71    4.80    137     11  317.0  332.7  317.9
590.0   4529    0.0   -4.1    74    4.81    143     11  317.6  333.3  318.5
577.0   4708   -1.1   -4.6    77    4.74    151     11  318.3  333.9  319.2
549.0   5108    0.5   -1.1    89    6.47    170     12  324.8  346.3  326.1
500.0   5850   -7.3  -11.9    70    3.09    205     13  324.1  334.7  324.7
484.5   6096   -7.0  -17.1    44    2.08    220     13  327.4  334.8  327.9
474.0   6267   -6.7  -20.7    32    1.56    223     13  329.8  335.5  330.1
457.0   6552   -7.5  -21.5    32    1.51    228     13  332.3  337.8  332.6
400.0   7580  -12.7  -26.7    30    1.08    245     12  338.4  342.5  338.6
357.0   8444  -16.5  -28.5    35    1.03    174     10  344.5  348.5  344.7
300.0   9730  -26.3  -37.3    35    0.52     65      6  348.2  350.3  348.3
250.0  11020  -36.5  -46.5    35    0.24     85      5  351.7  352.7  351.7
200.0  12530  -49.1  -58.1    34    0.07    135      8  354.9  355.2  354.9
170.0  13577  -57.1                                     358.4         358.4
```

Station information and sounding indices

```
                         Station identifier: VABB
                             Station number: 43003
                           Observation time: 730602/0000
                           Station latitude: 19.11
                          Station longitude: 72.84
                          Station elevation: 14.0
                            Showalter index: -2.44
                               Lifted index: -7.32
    LIFT computed using virtual temperature: -8.10
                                SWEAT index: 224.58
                                    K index: 29.90
                         Cross totals index: 21.10
                      Vertical totals index: 29.10
                        Totals totals index: 50.20
      Convective Available Potential Energy: 1252.58
             CAPE using virtual temperature: 1440.95
                      Convective Inhibition: -0.01
             CINS using virtual temperature: 0.00
                   Level of Free Convection: 943.36
             LFCT using virtual temperature: 944.28
                     Bulk Richardson Number: 237.98
          Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV: 273.77
  Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 296.48
Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 944.28
     Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 301.39
              Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 19.57
              1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5816.00
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 52.16
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PRES    HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT  SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
 hPa      m      C      C       %    g/kg    deg  knot     K      K      K 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000.0    14   32.4   26.4    71   22.27    270   12   305.6   372.9   309.6
967.9    304   25.8   21.9    79   17.42    310   10   301.8   353.4   304.9
961.0    368   24.4   20.9    81   16.48    310   10   300.9   349.6   303.9
935.0    609   26.1   20.2    70   16.27    310   11   305.0   353.9   308.0
933.0    628   26.2   20.2    70   16.25    310   11   305.3   354.2   308.3
903.0    914   25.2   18.3    65   14.88    315    7   307.2   352.4   310.0
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. You say "remove complete row from station to precipitable", but your example data doesn't contain any stations? Also, you should show us what you have attempted. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance on good practice when asking questions.

Comment: This makes no sense. There is a lot of data, none of which contains what you are looking for. This looks like a question that you have been given at school and don't understand yourself. It would be a lot more helpful if you could post relevant data and examples of what you have tried so far. That way, if we cant tell from the data post what you are trying to do, your code should give a better indication.

Answer (score 0):

This code will, from the bottom up, start removing rows when it finds "Precipitable" as the first word in the first column. It will stop when it finds the words "Station identifier:" as the first words.

```
Sub Main()

Dim rowCount As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim delete As Boolean
Dim s As String

rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For counter = rowCount To 1 Step -1

    s = Cells(counter, 1).Value

    If Left(s, InStr(s, " ")) = "Precipitable" Then    
        delete = True        
    End If

    If Left(s, InStr(s, " ")) = "Station identifier:" Then    
        deleteRow (counter)        
        delete = False        
    End If

    If (delete) Then    
        deleteRow (counter)    
    End If    

Next counter

End Sub
'------------
Sub deleteRow(counter As Long)
    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.delete
End Sub
```